# find values in sheet then replace different values for each column

Tags: excel, vba

how do you find a value in a sheet then replace with different values for each columns
i cant think of a way get the range of non contigous cells with the values to loop thru it

attached before and after below:

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: Use `.Find` and `.FindNext`. Search for these terms in stackoverflow/google. you will find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replace Character With Column Index

```
Sub ReplaceChar()

    Const Char As String = "a"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    
    Dim crg As Range, c As Long
    
    For Each crg In rg.Columns
        c = c + 1
        crg.Replace Char, c, xlWhole, , False
    Next crg
    
    MsgBox "Character replaced.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thanks  i tested it and it works on the data i posted but when i used it on my sheet with cells of data around the cells constant value it replaces the constant value with its corresponding column no. and not the value of c in the code, i cant figure out why

Comment: You may need to reference the range in a different way, e.g. `Set rg = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Columns("D:I"))`. Need to see the actual worksheet to be sure of the logic though. Also, it will get far more complicated if there are columns that need to be skipped when additionally using `Application.Match` or the `Find` method comes to mind.

Comment: tested it with the intersect it now starts at 1 correctly not the column no. but my actual range is column D:V but column H,M,R are empty so the numbering of c skips it likes allocate the num to the empty columns

Comment: I guess you could try to put the contents of the loop in an If statement: `If IsNumeric(Application.Match(Char, crg, 0)) Then` (to skip column ranges where `Char` is not found) or something like `If Application.CountA(crg) > 0 Then` (to skip emtpy column ranges).

Comment: after the for each line i used `If crg.Column = 8 Or crg.Column = 13 Or crg.Column = 18 Then GoTo skipcl` then the `skipcl:`before the next crg line, it now works, thanks for the help!

Comment: You can avoid the frowned upon `GoTo` by using the opposite: `If crg.Column <> 8 And crg.Column <> 13 And crg.Column <> 18 Then`.